# java.lang.LinkageError using spring and gradle

Tags: spring, gradle, linkageerror

I'm trying to deploy a spring mvc project on tomcat 8.0.22 . I user Gradle as project builder. When i try to lunch the project i have an **`error code 500`**.

This is how my project is :

**build.gradle file :**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' 

jar {
    baseName = 'demo'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") 
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.6.RELEASE'
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

**web.xml file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>LiveLizard-FrontEnd</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springmvcdispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springmvcdispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/springmvcdispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

**spring dispatcher (springmvcdispatcher-servlet.xml) file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nostatikmedia.livelizard.controller"></context:component-scan>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"></bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

**My controller (MainController.java) :**

```
package com.nostatikmedia.livelizard.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(){
        return "authenticate";
    }

}
```

**and here my view (authenticate.jsp) :**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HELLOW !</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

When i lunch my project on tomcat v8.0.22 i have this error :

```
GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet jsp a lancé une exception
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/view/authenticate_jsp, and the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) for resolved class, org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class objects for the type .getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager; used in the signature
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.authenticate_jsp._jspInit(authenticate_jsp.java:53)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:179)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Sounds like a dependency problem. Can you check your dependencies. Issue scope as provided for the conflicting one.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are packaging `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` (embedded Tomcat) dependency with your war.

Basically what you need to do in order to package a deployable war is to apply the `war` plugin, and set that dependency scope as `providedRuntime`.

```
apply plugin: 'war'
...
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    ...
}
```

For more, see [Spring boot Gradle plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html),

especially section **59.4 Packaging executable jar and war files**

This link: [create a deployable war file](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file), also maybe useful.